# Use Include Statement functionality in Join Statement in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've a linq query over two Entities like this

```
IQueryable<Employee> employees = CreateObjectSet<Employee>().AsQueryable();
IQueryable<Department> depts = CreateObjectSet<Department>().AsQueryable();

        var result = (from employee in employees                         
                      join dept in depts
                          on emp.DeptID equals dept.ID
                             select employee
```

My Employee entity has a navigation property for Department and return its whole object, but this query does not return the Department info, i guess i've to set the values in the select statment, something like this

```
                 var result = (from employee in employees                         
                      join dept in depts
                          on emp.DeptID equals dept.ID
                           ****  employee.Dept=dept            ****
                                select employee
```

I dont want to set all the properties of Employee class and hence return that new object, please tell me some better approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is you want to select all the employees along with their departments (correct me if I am wrong). If you have a navigational property, you won't need a join at all. You can use `Include` like this:

```
List<Employee> employeesWithDepartments = CreateObjectSet<Employee>().
                                          Include(e => e.Department).
                                          ToList();
```

Comment: No my actual query is very complex and include several tables and thus require joins, Your direction is right that i need something like "include", but i need it in context of "JOINS".

Comment: I will repeat: If you have a navigational property, you don't need Joins. You can add your actual query to the question and I can have a look how to add the `Include` to it.

Comment: Yes, i check and cross check and everything i required is in navigation properties, should i use where clause along with this as i need employees with specific EmployeeID

Comment: Good, then you can use `Include`. Yes, you can use where, e.g.  `objectSet.Include(e => e.Department).Where(e => e.Id == yourId)`

Comment: Two things more, one is I AM DUMB and other is YOU ARE GREAT.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

couldnt you use "let" statement as a hack ?

```
 var result = (from employee in employees                         
                  join dept in depts
                      on employee.DeptID equals dept.ID
                       let notUtile = employee.Dept=dept
                            select employee);
```

Comment: It gives me the error "An expression tree not contain an assignment operator" on the line with "let" keyword on it

Comment: arg. could you define the function employee.SetDept(dept) ? (then use it in the let statement)

Comment: Oh... i did not realized that your query was on Entity framework sets. I'm affraid you cannot do this coz "select" and "update" statements are not compatible in SQL.

Comment: So, There is no way to do this?

Comment: With only one request -which is a select!- ? I'm seriously doubting of it :-/